# split integers in a series by forward slash

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I am trying to split the integers in a series by forward slash by using `rsplit`   function of python but it does not work.

## Original Data

```
date
1/30/2015
1/30/2015
1/30/2015
1/30/2015
1/30/2015
1/30/2015
1/30/2015
1/30/2015
1/30/2015
1/30/2015
```

## expected Data

I want to split by '/'

```
    date

'1' '30' '2015'
'1' '30' '2015'
'1' '30' '2015'
'1' '30' '2015'
'1' '30' '2015'
'1' '30' '2015'
'1' '30' '2015'
```

purpose of doing this is to take the year in separate column. i was trying to use below code before.

```
date =  df['date']
split = date.rsplit("/")
OutputData['Year']=split[2]
```

split[2]-> is year in date series - purpose to take year in separate columns

many thanks in advance

## this is the error i get every time 'this is a series of objects'

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: or replace?  date.replace('/', " ") for Ex. ?

Comment: Is df a dictionary ?

Comment: split_data = data.split('/') ... day = split_data[0], month = split_data[1], year = split_data[2] ?

Comment: This question is missing some crucial information. Please try using [this tool](https://github.com/alexmojaki/askso) to help you write a clearer question.

Comment: @aBiologist df is a dataframe http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html

Comment: @ Paul Rooney both rsplit and split gives the same error,   @ aBiologist -df is my dataframe,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `str` accessor to use string methods on the series:

```
df["date"].str.rsplit("/")
```

Or to have them in different columns:

```
df["date"].str.rsplit("/", expand = True)
```

With a series, it might be better to work on datetime data:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime(df["date"]).dt.year
Out[10]: 
0    2015
1    2015
2    2015
3    2015
4    2015
5    2015
6    2015
7    2015
8    2015
9    2015
Name: date, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO it would be more useful to just convert the string to a `datetime` using [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) so you can perform arithmetic operations on it and if you want the year or any other date/time component you can use the vectorised [`dt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#datetimelike-properties) accessor:

```
In [23]:
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df

Out[23]:
        date
0 2015-01-30
1 2015-01-30
2 2015-01-30
3 2015-01-30
4 2015-01-30
5 2015-01-30
6 2015-01-30
7 2015-01-30
8 2015-01-30
9 2015-01-30

In [24]:
df['year'] = df['date'].dt.year
df

Out[24]:
        date  year
0 2015-01-30  2015
1 2015-01-30  2015
2 2015-01-30  2015
3 2015-01-30  2015
4 2015-01-30  2015
5 2015-01-30  2015
6 2015-01-30  2015
7 2015-01-30  2015
8 2015-01-30  2015
9 2015-01-30  2015
```